# Use data from variable to determine other variable in JSON

Tags: java, lombok, builder

I have defined an example JSON:

```
"BasicData": {
  "country": "United Kingdom"
},
"Phone": {
  "Phone prefix": "+44"
}
```

I am trying to build an object based on a value in another object. Phone prefixes should have determined by the country value (which will be passed as a parameter). Can we make this using builder and switch case statements in the Phone class, or are there any Lombok annotations that can help solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some way to determine the display name and phone prefix from the country (usually an ISO country code is used). This could be a service with hardcoded static data like this:

```
class Country {
    String displayName;
    String dialingCode;
}

class CountryService {   
    Map<String, Country> data = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        data.put("gb", new Country("United Kindom", "+44"));
    }
    Optional<Country> find(String isoCode) {
        if (isoCode == null) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(data.get(isoCode.toLowerCase()));
    }        
}
```

(or something more elaborate)

Then when you are constructing your JSON you can populate the BasicData with the display name, and the Phone with the prefix.

```
class Controller {

    CountryService countryService;

    Message handleRequest(String countryIsoCode) {
        Country country = countryService.find(countryIsoCode)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new BadRequestException());

        return new ResponseBuilder()
            .basicData(country.getDisplayName())
            .phone(country.getDialingCode())
            .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you will have a static list of countries with a static set of information (such as the phone prefix, the country code etc.), a way to approach this may be by creating an interface that exposes all the methods that are common to a country:

```
public interface ICountry {
    String getPhonePrefix();
}
```

... then to have an `enum` that implements the interface with all the known countries:

```
public enum Country implements ICountry {

    UK("United Kingdom") {
        @Override
        public String getPhonePrefix() {
            return "+44";
        }
    },
    IT("Italy") {
        @Override
        public String getPhonePrefix() {
            return "+39";
        }
    },
    FR("France") {
        @Override
        public String getPhonePrefix() {
            return "+33";
        }
    };

    private final String displayName;

    Country(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public static Country parse(String displayName) {
        for (Country value : Country.values()) {
            if (displayName.equals(value.getDisplayName())) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown country " + displayName);
    }
}
```

Hence, you would be able to receive `United Kingdom` as parameter and by mapping this value to the corresponding value of your enum, you'd have access to all the information you need for that country:

```
String countryName = "United Kingdom";
Country country = Country.parse(countryName);
System.out.println(country.getPhonePrefix());
>> "+44"
```